# Python - Performance degrades with multiprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I have a cpu intensive task running in a loop that calls OpenCV functions.
I tried to parallelize the task using multiprocessing, but the parallelized code runs slower than the serial code. 
I tried the following:

```py
def compute_homographies(present_objects, best_homographies):
    t1 = time.time()

    # The homographies dictionary is passed to the worker function and 
    # is a shared dictionary created using multiprocessing.Manager()       
    # After the workers finish, it should contain the best 
    # homography for each of the present objects.
    homographies = manager.dict()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    for source, target in present_objects:
        # get the best homography computed so far for this object
        best_homography = best_homographies[source.name]
        pool.apply_async(find_best_homographies, 
                                (source, target, homographies, best_homography, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Computing homographies took ", time.time() - t1)
    best_homographies.update(homographies)
    return homographies


def find_best_homographies(source, target, homographies, best_homography):
    t1 = time.time()
    #CPU intensive task, involving calling OpenCV
    homography = compute_homography(source, target)

    # checking if the computed homography is better 
    # than the best_homography. CPU intensive task
    # involves calling OpenCV. 
    if is_better(homography, best_homography):
        homographies[source.name] = homography
    else:
        homographies[source.name] = best_homography
    print("Finding homograpy for {} took {}".format(source.name, time.time() - t1))
```

If I run this code without multiprocessing, the `find_best_homographies` function takes about 50 to 80 miliseconds and the computation for all the objects takes about as much as the "*sum of individual calls* to `find_best_homographies`". 
If I run the above code, first each call to `find_best_homographies` takes almost twice as much, and the total call for all objects takes twice longer than even the sum of individual calls. I expected that the total time in the parallel case to be the maximum of the individual calls.

The `source` and `target` are instances of simple classes. They both contain a Numpy array to hold an RGB image of size roughly 300x300 pixels.

What is going wrong here? How can I achieve a better performance than the serial case?

I also tried to parallelize using Processes but the the result was the same.

Comment: Pouding the disk in parallel is generally a bad idea. If your in-memory computations are fast enough, doing so will indeed make your performance worse than serial.

Comment: It depends heavily on what the functions are doing. This is more a question fitted for code review, and you should provide the complete code (with an example that can be run) if you want help on code optimization.

Comment: That being said, you really don't have enough meaningful code to tell you why its happening for sure. Without seeing a minimal example, I don't have anything to look at or play with.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I removed the disk access (read and write) from code. The performance improved. But I still see the same weird pattern: _In serial case the function calls take less, and the total time is the sum of individual function calls. In parallel case, the function calls take longer, and the sum is twice or three times higher than the sum of individual calls._
I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of parallelization and speeddown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess... usually when CPU intensive work slows down when parallelised using processes, the reason for this is data transmission between processes.    If you call a function within your process, transmit it parameters and return something, data is "transferred" into the function and out of it by making in-memory copies of objects or just passing a reference pointer if immutable.   If you pass an argument to a pool worker and return result, this happens in practice using queues. This is much, much slower than making an in-memory copy.

In your case you also have the `Manager.dict()` object, which means even more data transfers using queues.

There is also something not quite right (probably) with the logic of your parallelised version. You use `apply_async()`, which passes a task to the pool but returns immediately without waiting for the task to complete. Your main program progressing to the next iteration of your for loop does not indicate a result is ready. There is a callback functionality in apply_async to do something when a result is available. If you expect to evaluate

```
best_homography = best_homographies[source.name]
```

after completion of each worker task, this does not happen in the program you have written. If your workers take some time to complete, your for loop completes in a fraction of time of a single worker and your program then waits in `join()` for all workers to finish, which means this line gets evaluated as many times as you have elements in your `present_objects` without a single worker submitting their result to the dictionary yet.

Comment: Passing objects between processes of the pool imposes a certain overhead.
Creating and handling the pool itself takes also a lot. I tested with a very small worker method. In my computer only creating the pool, doing the async_call, closing the pool and the join takes something between 150 to 200 ms. 
Regarding the logic, I don't think there is problem. I want homographies for different physical objects to be computed in parallel, and then return the dictionary for all objects. So I have to wait till the result for all objects is computed.